# Работа с LocalStorage из фреймворка gin

Tags: golang, localstorage

Есть необходимость работать с LocalStorage из back. 
Вообще для проекта использую gin.
Перебрал кучку библиотек, похожа на рабочую: [github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js](http://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/js)

Пытаюсь получить

```
obj := js.Global.Get("UID")
```

И что то у меня падает паника.
Возможно требуется как то подключить ее к gin?

Либо посоветуйте как мне получить данные из LocalStorage в golang.

- Таблица: UID;
- Переменная: UID_VAR;

Comment: Эм. Как вы собираетесь с бэкэнда получать доступ к LocalStorage, который на стороне клиента? GopherJS - это вообще используется, когда вы компилируете го в джаваскрипт.

Comment: Ну вот я и уточняю, можно ли получить туда доступ) Видимо нет.